# Grammar rule or reason?

Tags: grammar

Is the following a grammatical rule or reason?

> The noun phrase following the verb *be* in a sentence beginning with *there* is indefinite because *there* introduces new information, and new information in English is marked with an indefinite article.

Comment: There is Frank!

Comment: While there are exceptions (like counting: _There's Frank, Mary, and Bill; that's three already_), generally that's the case. _There_-Insertion moves the new information from the beginning to the end of the sentence, where it's more easily processed in English. So it's not a rule, just a tendency based on the kinds of sentences that _There_-Insertion applies to.

Comment: Yes and no. New information is not always marked by the indefinite article. Speakers also signal the *topic* of a new discourse with *the*. But probably not after *there is*.

Comment: It should be noted that there are several distinct meanings of "there", with somewhat different syntactic roles.

Answer (score 2):

I congratulate you on a shrewd piece of observation and reasoning. Indeed, this is usually the case with existential *there* (though not, of course, with ordinary locative *there*, as Hot Licks points out).

There is however an exception (there's *always* an exception, because this is Real Language). The definite article (and other definite determiners like *that*) does not mark its head specifically as 'old' to the discourse but as 'identifiable' within it; it may be in a sense 'old' within the universe of discourse and 'new' only within the immediate discourse. Consequently, if you introduce a new entity which is identifiable it is marked with the definite article:

> **A:** Where are we going to put the auditors while they're here?
>   **B:** Well, there's **the** small conference room—we can work around that being tied up for a week.

Comment: It always amazes me how complicated grammatical rules come naturally only on the basis that they *sound* right.